# When should you use deterministic models rather than stochastic models for a fitting problem?

Tags: time-series, regression

Lets say we have and ordered timestamped data. How to decide between deterministic and stochastic models? Under what circumstances deterministic is a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Deterministic models can sometimes be calculated analytically, and thus have faster training times (sometimes). Otherwise, most models have some stochastic aspects to allow for robustness or speed.